# How to populate form with name_city, and submit id_city when using `setTimeout(() => {`

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, settimeout, patch

I try to use autocomplete in my project. I have a problem when I populate form.
1. I want to display in html name of city, like in this [image]:

2. When I click button **Register** I want to submit id_city, like in this [image]
3. Also, when I remove or add items I want to submit id_city. In this part I have a problem. Because existing city submit name and new city submit id_city, like [image]:

My populate form:

```
populateform(){
      this.client.forEach(x => console.log(x));
    this.myform.patchValue({
      email: this.client.map(x => x.email),
      client_name: this.client.map(x => x.client_name),
    });
    city_id: this.client.forEach(x => {
      x.city_id.forEach(cid => {
        //this.formData.push(new FormControl(x.city_id))
        let control = new FormControl(cid, Validators.required);
        this.formData.push(control);
        setTimeout(() => {
          let cityName = this.city.find(c => c.city_id == cid).name;
          control.patchValue(cityName, { onlySelf: true, emitEvent: true });
        }, 100)
      });

    })
}
```

This is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g2hcvs-hy6xwq?file=app/autocomplete-overview-example.ts)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please can you review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide?
You should include your code in the question and not just as a demo link

Comment: Hi, Yes you are right, sorry! I need realy support. Can you look my problem code please?

Comment: I can't help I'm afraid, but now your question is better formatted, someone is bound to jump on it :-)